# Does Windows Phone 7 support page navigation with transition effects?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I know I can use

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pagei.xaml", UriKind.Relative))
```

to navigate among pages, does Windows Phone 7 support page navigation with transition effects?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't support it out of the box. You need to use [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/). Check sample application provided with SL Toolkit. There is a page with transition animations.